# Upgrading from ext3/4 to BTFS vs fresh install?

Tags: debian, ext4, btrfs

[According to Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Btrfs)

> Ext2/3/4 filesystems are upgradeable to Btrfs; however, upstream recommends backing up the data, creating a pristine btrfs filesystem with wipefs -a and mkfs.btrfs, and restoring from backup -- or replicating the existing data (eg: using tar, cpio, rsync etc).

Because Debian doesn't support BTRFS through installation, I'm comparing `wipefs`, `mkfs.btrfs` after install and the upgrade approach? Do you lose anything with the upgrade to btrfs with `btrfs upgrade` approach?

Comment: Are you talking about upgrade via btrfs-convert or about upgrade via mkfs & cp -a to a new filesystem?

Comment: added clarity @u1686_grawity

Comment: Debian _does_ support creating btrfs during installation since years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the liability that something goes wrong you need only

- Remove the original filesystem metadata with `btrfs subvolume delete`
- Defrag to make file extents more contiguous with `btrfs filesystem defrag`
- [Run `btrfs balance`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752589/3285)

Summary of [`btrfs convert`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-convert.html)