# What is the point of `btrfs balance` on one device?

Tags: btrfs

What is the point of doing [`btrfs balance`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-balance.html) on one device?

```
btrfs balance start /mnt
```

What benefit will that give if `/mnt` is hosted on a single drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTRFS during a conversion will use free space on the drive for its metadata block groups. Because free space can be fragmented the metadata block groups can be smaller then the default size -- they're bound by the free space layout. Running `btrfs balance` will merge these smaller block groups together, resulting in a more compact storage of metadata blocks.

https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-convert.html